# Enforcing and running apps with memory tagging extension

Tags: kernel, 22.04, security, ram

As you may already know, MTE is available in Ubuntu22LTS or above according to announcement.
We know that we can add arm64.nomte for disabling this feature. But we don't know how we can enable and enforce it?
Moreover, It is not activated by default. Because sample programs from these two shows MTE is not available by default and kernel does not advertise proper flags.

https://learn.arm.com/learning-paths/smartphones-and-mobile/mte/mte/

https://docs.kernel.org/next/arm64/memory-tagging-extension.html

Any idea on how to enable on Apple-M1 processor with Ubuntu 22 LTS?